# Cloud build pytest Can not find Ghostscript library

Tags: google-cloud-platform, yaml, ghostscript, google-cloud-build

I'm trying to create a trigger that test a function before deploying it in `cloud function`. So far I managed to install `requirements.txt` and execute `pytest` but I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ghostscript/__init__.py:35: in <module>
    from . import _gsprint as gs
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ghostscript/_gsprint.py:515: in <module>
    raise RuntimeError('Can not find Ghostscript library (libgs)')
E   RuntimeError: Can not find Ghostscript library (libgs)
```

I have `ghostscript` in my `requirements.txt` file :

```
[...]
ghostscript==0.6
[...]
pytest==6.0.1
pytest-mock==3.3.1
```

Here is my `deploy.yaml`

```
steps:
  - name: 'docker.io/library/python:3.7'
    id: Test
    entrypoint: /bin/sh
    dir: 'My_Project/'
    args:
    - -c
    - 'pip install -r requirements.txt && pytest pytest/test_mainpytest.py -v'
```

From the traceback, I understand that I don't have `ghostscript` installed on the cloud build, which is true.

Is there a way to install `ghostscript` on a step of my `deploy.yaml`?

Edit-1:

So I tried to install `ghostscript` using commands in a step, I tried `apt-get gs`, `apt-get ghostscript` but unfortunately it didn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The real problem is that you are missing a c-library, the package itself seems installed by pip. You should install that library with your package manager. This is an example for ubuntu-based containers:

```
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |
        apt update
        apt install ghostscript -y
        pip install -r requirements.txt
        pytest pytest/test_mainpytest.py -v
```

Comment: The problem isn't with pip, it work fine with all version of python as long as you update it, my problem is that I can't find a way to install ghostscript, everything else work fine. I must use cloud-build for reasons, but thanks for trying to help me !

Comment: Yes, I saw that later on. You have ghostscript installed with pip, but it cannot find the underlying c library. You have to install that as well!

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, but I can't find a way to install ghostscript using linux commands in a steps

Comment: You have to use the -y flag!

Comment: Thank you ! I added ```-y``` so that it look like this ```apt install ghostscript -y``` to accept the installation, and it worked !